# Show that the pedal equation of the curve $x=a(2\cos ⁡t-\cos⁡2t),\ y=a(2\sin ⁡t-\sin⁡2t)$ is $9(r^2-a^2 )=8p^2$

Tags: calculus, analytic-geometry

> Show that the pedal equation of the curve $x=a(2\cos ⁡t-\cos⁡2t),\
>  y=a(2\sin ⁡t-\sin⁡2t)$ is $9(r^2-a^2 )=8p^2$.

I have found $$\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx} = \frac{\cos θ-\cos2θ}{\sin2θ-\sin θ}.$$

Then I found the equation of tangent and applied the distance formula, but the equation gets complicated. Please, I really appreciate the help. Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://www.toppr.com/ask/question/at-any-points-of-the-curve-represented-parametrically-by-xa2-cos-t-cos-2t-ya2sin/ . It should I feel

Comment: No, the equation is same but both the questions are different

Comment: When did I gave you the complete same question? That question is for reference. Can you solve the question by taking the reference from the website?

Comment: I did try but in my question I have to convert it into pedal equation in terms of p and r but this reference question can't tackle changes in the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Finding pedal equation of the given curve][image][image]

This is the required pedal equation. In this question, $x^2+y^2$ and $1+{(\frac{dy}{dx})}^2$ can be easily reduced to simpler terms, so one should try to proceed further even if equation starts looking complicated.